# django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The SECRET_KEY sett ing must not be empty

Tags: django, production-environment, secret-key

I am forking a free Django project on git. The files have no Secret_Key- as you can appreciate.
It has a env folder with files and env.md.
The env.md request to enter all the Values:

- Kindly add below environment variables to your local development with appropriate key/value accordingly.

#### Common keys

> DEBUG=True #false
> SECRET_KEY="(I have entered here, a python random generated 50 character as the Secret_key)"
> HTML_MINIFY=True/False
> ENV_TYPE="DEV" or "PROD"

File "/opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/
management/**init**.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line utility.execute()
File "/opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/
management/**init**.py", line 395, in execute
self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
File "/opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/
management/base.py", line 330, in run_from_argv
self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
File "/opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/
management/commands/runserver.py", line 61, in execute
super().execute(*args, **options)
File "/opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/
management/base.py", line 371, in execute
output = self.handle(*args, **options)
File "/opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/
management/commands/runserver.py", line 68, in handle
if not settings.DEBUG and not settings.ALLOWED_HOSTS:
File "/opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/conf/
**init**.py", line 83, in **getattr**
self._setup(name)
File "/opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/conf/
**init**.py", line 70, in _setup
self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
File "/opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/conf/
**init**.py", line 196, in **init**
raise ImproperlyConfigured("The SECRET_KEY setting must not
be empty.")
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The SECRET_KEY sett
ing must not be empty.

I have created a ´random python´ Secret_key as I expect you don't leave your Secret:_key , debug and Database on the git.

what i´ve done_:
I found the env.md and entered a random Secret_key in the Key Value as above.
I ran runserver but it still has same error.

The next thing done:
I also found in the sitepackages/..Django/conf/global_settings .
and pasted also the random generated python  Secret_ key as it was blank.

I did runserver but it still says the same error.

Can you advise ?
How come after entering the random Secret_Key I get the same error above.

If I have a project to go to git or production ive read you use python decouple or setup the django environment to do with base.py. but as this is using someones free git with missing secret key. I wondered if anyone has managed to resolve that...

Thank you for advises.

Comment: use all caps `SECRET_KEY` not `Secret_key`

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the secret key you have created, to your `settings.py`. Let's assume your project is MyProject, your settings.py should be in this directory:

```
MyProject:/
    MyProject:/
        settings.py
```

You should add this line:

```
# settings.py
SECRET_KEY="ENTER HERE"
```

A better practice is, creating a `settings_local.py` and put your sensitive settings (e.g. secret keys, passwords etc) in this file. And after that in your original `settings.py` at the last line, you should import this file. Like:

```
# settings_local.py
SECRET_KEY="ENTER HERE"

# settings.py
from settings_local import *
```

This file also should be ignored by git (e.g put it in your .gitignore) so that you dont push your secret information on git.